# How to rename rows in a column with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 merged csv datasets and I need to rename the rows putting only the abbreviation, like "new york" becomes "NY".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.rename(columns={"<old_col_name>": "<new_col_name>"}, inplace= True)
```

don't forget to add inplace=True to update the changes right away, or you can write it like

```
df = df.rename(columns={"<old_col_name>": "<new_col_name>"})
```

**misread at first**
this is how

```
***df["<col_name>"] = df["<col_name>"].replace("New York", "NY")***
```

Comment: how do i add more edits? like this:
df["<col_name>"] = df["<col_name>"].replace("New York", "NY", "Los Angeles", "LA")

Comment: in the case you'll have to use a dictionairy

df["<col_name>"] = df["<col_name>"].replace({"New York": "NY", ""Los Angeles": "LA"})

and so on the dict.key will be the old value you want to change, and dict.value will be the new value, and you can add as many as you want

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df.<your_column_name>.replace(to_replace='new york', value='NY')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can scrape a table that has the conversion and merge:

```
df = pd.read_html("https://abbreviations.yourdictionary.com/articles/state-abbrev.html")[0]
df = df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0]).drop(df.index[0])[["State Name", "USPS Abbreviation"]]

data = {
    "States": ["Alabama", "New York", "Kansas"],
    "Number": [1, 2, 3]
}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)


final_df = pd.merge(df, df2, left_on="State Name", right_on="States").drop(columns="States")

print(final_df)

  State Name USPS Abbreviation  Number
0    Alabama                AL       1
1     Kansas                KS       3
2   New York                NY       2
```